# No rights to access C

Tags: administrator, privileges

I have a fresh copy of Windows 7 installed on my new Samsung 830 128 Gb SSD. When I copy files to or from C drive it prompts me a message if I want to use administrator privileges. For example, if I want to run Photoshop from a shortcut on desktop, I have to right click it and select run as an administrator because my normal account doesn't have rights to modify or execute on the C drive.

I haven't modified the users privileges. Last Windows installation worked on HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "modify or execute on the C drive" you are referring to files in the *root* of the C drive, then yes, you need admin privileges to change or create files and folders in the root folder.  But you should be able to access `C:\users\YOURUSERNAME\Documents` without problem.

Comment: Yes, actually I didn't test so far that I would have noticed that. I just copied files from root of C and it asked me the administrator rights. Thanks!